# How to return an array of asynchronous, dependant pipes using rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I’m currently trying to return an array of completed observable responses from an angular service using an observable with N number of pipes applied to it. I’m not very familiar with rxjs as I’ve just recently gotten into front end development so I’m unsure if I’m doing so incorrectly.

The service is called by an angular component and needs to go as follows in an asynch fashion:

1. Call an API to create a ticket in draft status
2. Loop through N number of attachments and call another API to attach them to the ticket created above using the info obtained from part 1
3. Call another API to create the ticket in complete status using info from part 1 ONLY if part 2 completes
4. Return an observable that can be subscribed to that contains the return information from parts 2 and 3 (something like an array where the first N results are the attachment return information and the last is the API set to complete status, or vice-versa)

This is what I’m working with so far which functions properly, but does not return properly:

```
submitRequestAttachments(serviceName: any, request: any, attachments: FormData[]) {

    let obs: Observable<any>;

    return serviceName.set(request).pipe(switchMap((result: any) => {

        [...error handling...]

        request["uniqueID"] = result.uniqueID;


        obs = this.uploadFile(attachments[0], result.uniqueID);

        for(let i = 1; i < attachments.length; i++) {

            obs = obs.pipe(switchMap((a_result: any) => {

                [...error handling...]

                return this.uploadFile(attachments[i], result.uniqueID);

            }

        }

        return obs.pipe(switchMap((b_result: any) => {

            [...error handling...]

            return serviceName.set(request);

        }
    }
}
```

Variables and types have been obfuscated, but essentially that's what I'm working with. I've attempted using mergeMaps, toArray(), and forkJoin with little success. With forkJoin I was able to get the right return, but it was calling the first attachment upload 3 times instead of 1 which is not intended. Any help would be appreciated. I imagine the issue is in my RxJS operators and how I'm piping every call yet I don't know how to incorporate N API calls that need to asynchronously complete before the final API call.

Comment: are you looking for `merge(attachments.map(att => this.uploadFile(att, result.uniqueID)))`?